# Comparing strings in format 00:00:00

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating strings that represent road race times and I'm trying to sort through and break them down to see which string is the fastest time. What is the best algorithm or approach to do so? I've tried `componentsSeparatedByString@":"` as well as formatting the time to a NSDate time, but neither work successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: Post what you have tried so people can help you solve whatever issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question; 
assuming the time string is divided in hours:minutes:seconds you can use

```
NSArray *timeComponents = NSArraycomponentsSeparatedByString:@":"
```

and from your array you will have:

```
NSString *hour = timeComponents[0];
NSString *minutes = timeComponents[1];
NSString *seconds = timeComponents[2];
```

My advice than would be to convert the first two down to seconds:

```
double hourInSeconds = hour.doubleValue * 3600;
double minutesInSeconds = minutes.doubleValue * 60;
```

add everything together:

```
double allInSeconds = hourInSeconds + minutesInSeconds + seconds.doubleValue
```

and so do your comparisons, the smaller the value the faster the time.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found `NSComparisonResult` to work and comparing my best time to my current time and checking to see if `NSOrderDescending` was true worked.

Comment: How did you compare the two strings? I just wanna see how good I did understand your answer.